# Show html text into DataGrid - Silverlight

Tags: c#, html, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm afraid that I have a really hard problem. I need to show **html text** into a Silverlight DataGrid, I've been trying with the third party Devexpress datagrid and I have no idea how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Silverlight 4 and the app is running out of browser you might want to give the [WebBrowser](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/11/18/silverlight-4-rough-notes-html-hosting-in-the-webbrowser-control.aspx) control a go.

In most other cases I'd try to transform the HTML into XAML.

This could also be [an interesting approach](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/51784.aspx) putting [a div over the silverlight app](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/20577/71127.aspx#71127)